# How to maintain SQL Server DB with lots of branches

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET project under git where we follow the convention of using a branch for a feature. We just started using SQL Server Data Tools to manage schema changes (quite new to it, so I suspect it may have features that get me to what I need).

I am looking for some strategies that have worked for other teams that manage switching between branches that have different DB schemas and then successfully merging branches together. Ideally, after merging all the features, I would have implicitly created a change script(s) to deploy for the release to production.

Note I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I've used RedGate SQL Compare in the past when I have 2 out of sync schema's - it will analyse both DB's and script off the modifications needed into a query that you can then run to "upgrade" the desired DB. Check it out here http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=sqlcompare&gclid=CKzZhPyVl7MCFebLtAodSVkASA

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple parts to this strategy. One aspect is the handling of the *storage* of the different branches, and what has worked well for my teams has been to use different SQL Server instances for each branch (rather than naming individual databases with branch-specific prefixes or suffixes, e.g., MyDatabase_FeatureBranchX, which can get out of hand). This enables the corresponding database(s) in each branch to have the same names (for clarity) but also allows for physical and logical isolation of a given branch's SQL resources (data files, access permissions, etc.).

As for the second, more interesting aspect (which I think is the main intent of your question), you might consider utilizing a code-based "migrations" approach -- e.g., using [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator) or the like. Provided that you've got a standard baseline schema from which each branch was initially created, you can create the appropriate migrations in code as part of your feature development in each branch (and apply them to that branch's SQL instance). When it comes time to merge the branch into trunk, you'd also be merging and then applying that branch's migrations.

At best, this means that you could simply run the migration tool against your trunk instance after the merge, in order to apply all the branch's migrations, since tools like this automatically keep track of which migrations have been applied (via a custom database table) and do not reapply them. Provided that you're also doing periodic merges of your trunk code (including its migrations) into your feature branch throughout its development, and you're applying those migrations, you would also be ensuring that your feature branch's schema is being kept up to date, which minimizes the nasty surprises at merge time.

When it comes time to deploy your trunk to production, these same migrations would be applied once again. FluentMigrator offers various [runners](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Migration-Runners): a console application, NAnt, MSBuild, and Rake.

I would highly recommend using a timestamp-based (e.g., 201210241033) migration ID strategy, rather than simple sequential integers (1, 2, ...), to minimize the likelihood of collisions and changes being applied out of the intended sequence.